# IntelliJ 12, module-depenencies all red, no path.

Tags: intellij-idea, playframework-2.0

I have a real problem with making Play2.0 work with IntelliJ EAP version (120.152).

I create an empty project without module in IntelliJ
I create a new application using the play command, and using play idea at the end
I then add this module from IntelliJ, using "Import from existing module"

```
Now, I have two folders too chose from when importing the module. 
1. .idea
2. .idea_modules
After seeing some different ways on the internet, 
I chose .idea_modules -> moduleName.iml 
(I have tried all the others just to check)
```

Here is what bothers me the most
[image: module section]
Anyone had anything similar? I am not sure why this is, every other screenshot I have seen from this, have a path behind the red text (making it work!), which I do not.

Any suggestions what I can do from here to hopefully make this work?

My Scala facet looks like this in the IDE, but I have not seen any Play documentation that goes into modifying the facet, so I just leaved it as is
[image: scala facet]

Comment: IDEA 12 is pre-alpha quality, such issues should be reported at http://youtrack.jetbrains.net/issues/IDEA or in the EAP Users forum at http://devnet.jetbrains.net/community/idea/eap.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In `IntelliJ 12` - the same as in `IntelliJ 11` you can open the Play's project since version 2.0.2, just by using option 'Open project' in the start window view.

You don't need to create blank project first in IDE.

1. `play new test-leda` + all required steps by play console
2. `cd test-leda`
3. `play idea` + wait for bash prompt which indicates finalization
4. Open `Leda` and choose `Open project`
5. Find the folder `test-leda` and just click `Choose`

That's all

Comment: Thank you, this should be in the official documentation